# Which is the more important switching parameter in MOSFET datasheet? Turn on/off/delay times or Input/Output/Reverse capacitances?

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

I see both capacitance and timing details mentioned in the MOSFET datasheets.([Ref:](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_IPP075N15N3_DS_v02_06_en-1731900.pdf))

Which one should be considered for comparing the MOSFET switching performance between 2 MOSFET part numbers?

[image]

Note: I understand turn on/off/delay times are based on test circuit conditions as well ( Rg, VGs etc) and not an intrinsic property.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Which one should be considered for comparing the MOSFET switching
> performance between 2 MOSFET part numbers?*

Neither, if you are interested in a real circuit that switches a real load powered from a power supply that is reasonably close to the normal limit that you would use this device. So, this device is rated (absolute maximum) for a \$V_{DS}\$ of 150 volts and, a current of 100 amps but, if you look at the data sheet on page 3 you will see a figure called total gate charge.

For this device it is typically 70 nC. Along side that figure are some words describing the test.

Those words describe the scenario of 75 volts across the device and, when activated, a load limits the current to 100 amps. The gate voltage is also mentioned as rising to 10 volts from 0 volts. So, with 70 nC needed to raise the gate to 10 volts we can say that the effective input capacitance is 7 nF (Q = CV). But, it could be as high as 9.3 nF. That's almost double of what the stated input capacitance is.

You then have to consider what your gate driver circuit can deliver in terms of current and, you might decide that it is equivalent to 10 Ω source impedance.

That 10 Ω and the 9.3 nF produce an RC time of 93 ns and I would say that is a decent benchmark figure for making comparisons with other MOSFETs.

But, you have to read the words carefully and decide if the drain voltage and drain current scenarios are similar enough in different data sheets to make a valid judgement.

Answer (score 5):

Timing tells you how long it will take for it to switch. So this sets the speed you can operate them, setting maximum frequencies which you can use.

Capacitance tells you how much energy you need to do the switch. So this will set your driving circuitry and what cooling and power sources you require.

Looking at it another way: the timing limits how quickly you can do things, the capacitance tells you how efficiently you can do things. So to answer your question: they are both as important as each other. Your application will tell you what limits you can take for either.

Comment: Capacitance *sort of* tells you switching energy. The fact that the capacitance changes significantly during the switching event means that it's hard to compute from capacitance numbers alone. It's gate charge that you want, not Ciss. Some transistors will have a specified "energy-equivalent" and "timing-equivalent" capacitances listed on the datasheet, which can be used to calculate the losses due to capacitance and switching timing respectively, under a limited range of operating conditions.